# strace does not show the complete write

Tags: linux, strace

Im trying to view the data being written to an HTTP socket using strace
However, although I have given -e write=all, I still cannot see all the data being written

```
strace -o /tmp/capture.log -p <pid> -e trace=all -e write=all -e read=all -f -tt
 ..
 29620 16:09:14.723120 write(1899, "POST /task/native.wsdl HTTP/1.1\r"..., 210) = 210
 29620 16:09:14.723319 write(1899, "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http:"..., 450) = 450
```

What is strange is that, it shows the complete data during some other writes to other sockets

```
31145 16:09:28.110571 write(359, "POST /task/native.wsdl HTTP/1.1\r"..., 210) = 210
 | 00000  50 4f 53 54 20 2f 74 61  73 6b 2f 6e 61 74 69 76  POST /task/nativ |
 | 00010  65 2e 77 73 64 6c 20 48  54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d  e.wsdl HTTP/1.1. |
 | 00020  0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74  2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 74  .Content-Type: t |
 | 00030  65 78 74 2f 78 6d 6c 3b  20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74  ext/xml; charset |
 | 00040  3d 55 54 46 2d 38 0d 0a  41 63 63 65 70 74 3a 20  =UTF-8..Accept:  |
 | 00050  2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 53 4f 41  50 41 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a  */*..SOAPAction: |
 | 00060  20 22 22 0d 0a 55 73 65  72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a   ""..User-Agent: |
 | 00070  20 41 70 61 63 68 65 20  43 58 46 20 32 2e 37 2e   Apache CXF 2.7. |
 | 00080  31 31 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74  3a 20 65 73 2d 73 76 63  11..Host: es-svc |
 | 00090  73 2e 69 74 2e 61 74 74  2e 63 6f 6d 3a 37 30 30  s.it.att.com:700 |
 | 000a0  33 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65  63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 4b  3..Connection: K |
 | 000b0  65 65 70 2d 41 6c 69 76  65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65  eep-Alive..Conte |
 | 000c0  6e 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74  68 3a 20 34 35 30 0d 0a  nt-Length: 450.. |
 | 000d0  0d 0a                                             ..               |
```

Can somebody please explain. Is it possible to get data from all writes

Comment: This looks like a bug. What version of strace do you have?

Comment: `[sa8331@zlpv5940 ~]$ strace -V
strace -- version 4.8
[sa8331@zlpv5940 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)`

Answer (score 2):

The strace `-e write=a,b` flag shows write syscalls for file descriptors numbered from a to b, and `-e write=all` shows write syscalls to all file descriptors.
What you're looking for is `-e abbrev=none`; see the manpage:

```
-e abbrev=set
    Abbreviate  the  output from printing each member of large structures.  
    The default is abbrev=all.  The -v option has the effect of abbrev=none.
```

Comment: But according to the man page
`-e write=set
Perform a full hexadecimal and ASCII dump of all the data written to file descriptors listed in the specified set. For example, to see all output activity on file descriptors 3 and 5 use -e write=3,5. Note that this is independent from the normal tracing of the write(2) system call which is controlled by the option -e trace=write.`

I interpreted this to mean that all data will be shown for -e write=all
Besides anotehr writes() shows just that